# ftp_put working for month, now has stopped?

Tags: php, upload, ftp

Hi have the below syntax:

```
$source = $csv_filename;  
$target = '/locexport/'.$csv_filename;
$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.server.com") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn, "ftpusername", "ftppassword");

ftp_pasv($conn, false); 

$upload = ftp_put($conn, $target, $source, FTP_ASCII);
if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }
```

This script runs with cron jobs every few hours and has worked for months.

it has suddenly stopped working.

echoing $source and $destination shows the correct paths.

error message is:

```
Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Opening ASCII mode data connection. in /home/shareduser/public_html/export/export.php on line 55
FTP upload failed!
```

line 55 is:

```
 $upload = ftp_put($conn, $target, $source, FTP_ASCII);
```

I have tried changing FTP_ASCII to FTP_BINARY but with the same result.

any ides how to troubleshoot this? it is not a permission issue as a manual transfer in Filezilla with the same credentials succeeds.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Related: [PHP ftp_put fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40720260/850848).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to switch to passive mode (set it to `true`):

```
ftp_pasv($conn, true);
```

Maybe something has changed in destination's firewall.

Comment: Thanks. I did try this, sorry should have mentioned it in question, no luck and problem remains? how to troubleshoot? Thanks.

Comment: did you try to use a FTP program just to see if you can connect and has access to write a file?

Comment: Thanks. yes I did try that, did a manual transfer with filezilla using same ftp credentials and it worked 100%. Just the php component failing and I am not sure why. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, yes I did a manual transfer with filezilla and 100%. moved this script to another server and it worked perfectly so its a problem with my hosting server, not the ftp server or the script. thanks for your time though.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I was dealing with FTP backup code that had stopped working after bumping PHP version. Enabling passive mode after using `ftp login` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem here, but the Warning I get is:
`ftp_fput(): Accepted data connection`

Used FTP_BINARY, FTP_ASCII
used passive/active modes, no luck. 
Could be a bug? see [Bug #46531 ftp_put returns error on Accepted data connection](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46531)

**EDIT:**
Found a workaround, not sure it will work for anyone as it involves SSL connection, the bad thing is it was working fine until last PHP update (updated to 5.6.14)

Solution: don't use `ftp_ssl_connect` use `ftp_connect` instead