# PHP ftp_put fails

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I upload XML file through FTP:

```
$ftp = "ftp";
$username = "username";
$pwd = "password";
$filename = $_FILES[$xyz][$abc];
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$destination = "/Content/EnquiryXML ";

$connect = ftp_connect($ftp)or die("Unable to connect to host");
ftp_login($connect,$username,$pwd)or die("Authorization Failed");
echo "Connected!<br/>";              

if(!$filename)
{
    echo"Please select a file";
}

else
{
    ftp_put($connect,$destination.'/'.$filename,$tmp,FTP_ASCII)or die("Unable to upload");
    echo"File successfully uploaded to FTP";
}
```

I want to send the XML file created using `DOMDocument` to a FTP server but I am not able.

The `ftp_put` returns false.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Most typical cause of problems with `ftp_put` (or any other transfer command like `ftp_get`, `ftp_nlist`, `ftp_rawlist`, `ftp_mlsd`) is that PHP defaults to the active mode. And in 99% cases, one has to switch to the passive mode, to make the transfer working. Use the [`ftp_pasv` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php).

```
$connect = ftp_connect($ftp) or die("Unable to connect to host");
ftp_login($connect, $username, $pwd) or die("Authorization failed");
// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($connect, true) or die("Unable switch to passive mode");
```

*The `ftp_pasv` must be called after `ftp_login`. Calling it before has no effect.*

See also:

- [PHP ftp_put fails with "Warning: ftp_put (): PORT command successful"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39945860/850848)
- *my* article on the [active and passive FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

---

Further, if your FTP server is reporting an incorrect IP address in the response to the `PASV` command (what is quite common, if the server is behind firewall/NAT), you might need to workaround it by using:

```
ftp_set_option($connect, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);
```

See [PHP FTP + Passive FTP Server Behind NAT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38982901/850848).

*Though the right solution in this case, is to get the server fixed.*

Answer (score -2):

This worked:

```
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "host";
$ftp_username = "username";
$ftp_userpass = "password";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
$file ="$abc";

// upload file 
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, "/$abc" , $file, FTP_ASCII)){
    echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
} else {
    echo "Error uploading $file";
}

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

Comment: What worked? There's no `ftp_pasv` in your code! And do not use answer to comment on another answer.