# ftp_put returned TRUE but no file uploaded

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

Trying to upload a file to an FTP server using HTML form and PHP. My HTML form is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="files" id="files">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

uploader.php:

```
<?php
$conn_id = ftp_connect ( 'ftp.mydomain.com' );
$ftp_user_name="<username>";
$ftp_user_pass="<password>";

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login ( $conn_id , $ftp_user_name , $ftp_user_pass );

// check connection
if ((! $conn_id ) || (! $login_result )) {
    echo "FTP connection has failed!" ;
    exit;

} else {
    echo "Connected to for user $ftp_user_name" ;
}

if (empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "No file!!!!!!!!!";
    die();
}
// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put( $conn_id, "uploads/" , $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] , FTP_BINARY );

// check upload status
if(!$upload){
    echo "FTP upload has failed!" ;
} else {
    echo "Successfully Uploaded." ;
}
?>
```

The output I got is `Successfully Uploaded.`, but no file in actual can be found uploaded in the server.

`uploads/` directory is located in the same uploader.php directory. Trying to change it to `uploads/somename.zip` shows that `uploads/somename.zip is not a valid directoty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of [`ftp_put`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) is a path to a *remote file*, not a path to a *local directory*.

So it should be like:

```
ftp_put($conn_id, "/remote/path/somename.zip", $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY);
```

---

Also, you should use a passive mode. See [PHP ftp_put fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40720260/850848).