# ftp_put, can make folders but not upload files

Tags: php

I got a weird problem using ftp_put.

My code works perfectly when connecting to my old linux server (ftp_connect), but fails when trying to upload files to the new windows server (client choice) - we're running Filezilla Server on the windows server.

- Can connect to the windows server works (ftp_connect).
- Creating folders works (ftp_mkdir).
- Uploading files does not work - no idea why (ftp_put).
- I can upload files using FileZilla.
- User has full permissions on the Filezilla Server.
- Connecting to "C:/FTP" when connecting to the windows server.

I'm completely lost, got no idea what is causing these errors.
Maybe one of you might be able to point me in the right direction.

Does my code need to change path, when changing from a linux to windows server? The folder structure is 100% identical (file has to be saved within a folder named "SE").

This is my code:

```
# Conf ID
$conf_id = '7AEHQ6GS'; // for testing

# Files
$file1 = "xml/$conf_id/cylinder-tube.xml";

# FTP info
$ftp_host = '';
$ftp_port = '';
$ftp_user = '';
$ftp_pass = '';


# Connect to FTP server
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_host, $ftp_port, 10);

# Connect to FTP Server
if($conn_id) {

    if(@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {

        if(file_exists($file1)) {

            # Change directory
            ftp_chdir($conn_id, 'SE');

            # Create folder
            ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $conf_id);

            # Change directory
            ftp_chdir($conn_id, $conf_id);

            # Upload files
            if(
                ftp_put($conn_id, basename($file1), $file1, FTP_BINARY)
            ) {

                # Delete local files
                @unlink($file1);

                # Delete local folder
                rmdir("xml/$conf_id");

            }else{
                $st['status'] = 'FTP003';
                die(json_encode($st));
            }
        }else{      
            $st['status'] = 'FEJL011';
            die(json_encode($st));
        }
    } else {
        $st['status'] = 'FTP002';
        die(json_encode($st));
    }
}else{
    $st['status'] = 'FTP001';
    die(json_encode($st));
}
```

This is where my code is failing:

```
ftp_put($conn_id, basename($file1), $file1, FTP_BINARY)
```

Thanks,

Kenneth

Comment: It might be to do with the path. Can you try using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` or \ instead of `/`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion vivek_23. I just that, but still no files is being uploaded.$file1 = 'xml'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$conf_id. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'cylinder-tube.xml';

Comment: Ok, try with a \

Comment: Hmm.. then the php code will fail i think, since its running on linux. Only the FTP server is on a windows server.

Comment: I tested it but see no difference. Update: It actually fails here: file_exists($file1), since the path is wrong after changing to "\" (php code is running on linux)

Comment: Ok, is your folder structure like this- `SE/7AEHQ6GS/xml/7AEHQ6GS/cylinder-tube.xml`?

Comment: No, it's SE/7AEHQ6GS/cylinder-tube.xml

Comment: ftp_put($conn_id, cylinder-tube.xml, xml/7AEHQ6GS/cylinder-tube.xml, FTP_BINARY)

Comment: "xml" folder is on the local-php server. "SE" folder is on the FTP servers :)

Comment: Ahh!! Sorry my bad. Try with FTP_ASCII. Also, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720260/php-ftp-put-fails

Comment: It was passive mode! Thanks for the link (already tried FTP_ASCII earlier). Using this worked: ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die("Unable switch to passive mode");

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you post an answer with the link and ftp_pasv, so I can accept your solution? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ftp_put()` is failing, it is quite possible that it is due to a firewall protection. So, this happened because the connection is in `ACTIVE` mode.

Switch to `PASSIVE` mode with the help of [ftp_pasv()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php) to pass through the firewall security.

More details on active and passive FTP connections can be found [here](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)