# PHP uploading file from browser to FTP

Tags: php, ftp, upload

I want to upload files from user's machine to folder `uploads` in my FTP and it doesn't work. Can you help me?

```
$ftp_server = "some ip";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, "some name", "some password");

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = basename($_FILES["filename"]["name"]);

if (ftp_fput($ftp_conn, $target_dir.$target_file, FTP_ASCII))
  {
  echo "Successfully uploaded $target_file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error uploading $target_file.";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what local file (as of the webserver) you want to upload to the FTP server.

You can retrieve a name of a temporary file that contains a file uploaded via HTTP POST from user's machine to your webserver using [`$_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php). Read about [POST method uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) in PHP.

You can then pass that to [`ftp_put`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) (no need for `ftp_fput`):

```
$remote_filename = $target_dir . $target_file;
$local_filename = $_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"];
ftp_put($ftp_conn, $remote_filename, $local_filename, FTP_BINARY)
```

---

Two other issues in your code (which are not your immediate problems, but you will face them right after you resolve it):

- Absolutely do not use `FTP_ASCII`, if you are uploading binary files, like `.mp3`. Use `FTP_BINARY`.
- You [need to use `ftp_pasv`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40720260/850848).