# ftp_put(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory

Tags: php, ftp, upload

I search a lot on internet but i don't find a solution.
I need upload a file to an FTP server through PHP.

I  tested various script PHP like this below but I always receive the same problem (I tries with absolute, normal and other path):

> connected
> Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory in /web/htdocs/www.stanem.it/home/csv/importinnovacsv.php on line 20
> There was a problem while uploading /web/htdocs/www.stanem.it/home/csv/test.csv

What I have to do?

```
<?php
$ftp_server="ftp.xxxx.it";
$ftp_user_name="user";
$ftp_user_pass="psw";

// connect and login to FTP server

$ftp_conn       = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login          = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if($login) {
   echo 'connected<br>'; 

   // Where I need to put file
   $local_file = '/web/htdocs/www.stanem.it/home/csv/test.csv'; 
   // Where I copy the file
   $server_dir = 'ftp://15886:XDBbcFYQUs@ftp.innovaspa.it'; 

   // upload a file
   if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $server_dir, $local_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
       echo "successfully uploaded $local_file\n";
       exit;
   } else {
       echo "There was a problem while uploading $local_file\n";
       exit;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$remote_file` argument of [`ftp_put`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) is a **path** to the **file** on the FTP server.

You are passing a **URL** (and it even misses any path or file name).

It should be like:

```
$remote_file = "/remote/path/test.csv";
```

---

Once you resolve the path problem, you will also likely face data connection problems, as your are using the default active mode. See [PHP ftp_put fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40720260/850848).