# Create and upload a new file via ftp in php

Tags: php, server, ftp

Is it possible to upload a new file in ftp instead of rewrite an old one? I need code for creating a new file and uploading it into the server via ftp. If I try to upload it via `ftp_put()`, it does not work.

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
    $ftp = ftp_connect("web");
ftp_login($ftp, "user", "pass");
echo ftp_put($ftp, "Tulassi/tulasi_test", $objPHPExcel, FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($ftp);
    exit;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need to upload a new file to server via ftp(not overwrite)

Comment: So what is stopping you doing that, precisely? "not works" isn't an error message or a clear problem statement. As long as the file you're writing has a filename which doesn't already exist in the (same folder of) the FTP server, it should not overwrite anything else.

Comment: i don't know is this is correct code or not can you plz share the code for create and upload  a file to ftp

Comment: You *have* a code that creates and uploads a file to FTP. If it does not work, and you need our help, you will have to describe your problem to us. As a wild guess, I'll point you to  [PHP ftp_put fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40720260/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ok i check there ,i don't know is this is correct code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "";
$ftp_user_name = "";
$ftp_user_pass = '';
$destination_file = "new.xls";
$source_file = $objWriter; 

// set up basic connection
$conn_id =  ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
     
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_ASCII); 

if (!$upload) { 
echo "FTP upload has failed!112";
} else {
echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}  
// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is this? Is this a solution? Or what?