# ftp_ssl_connect and ftp_nlist

Tags: php, ftp, ssl-certificate, ssh2-sftp

I need to connect to a remote system to get some files. The specs of the remote system mention that:

> The Protocol required is SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol
> The Port Number is 22

Before anything else, I used my FTP client app to try to log into the new server using the given credentials.

At first I (following the system's specs) used a *SFTP over SSH* connection type and indeed it worked fine.

[image]

I researched how one can access a remote resource using SFTP over SSH in PHP, and I got the ssh2 set of commands... But my server doesn't have ssh2 commands installed, nor am I familiar with how to further deal with that in terms of listing and downloading remote files, etc (I'm used to plain `ftp_connect()`, `ftp_login()` and `ftp_nlist()` commands)...

So I tried other options in my FTP client app, and found that despite the new system's specs, it connected fine using *FTP using explicit SSL (Auth SSL)* and *FTP using explicit SSL (Auth TLS)* connection types also (the only difference is that in those cases I got a popup asking me to accept and store the remote certificate. Of course I got a list of the remote files also...

So, I researched the implementation of FTP connection using explicit SSL in PHP and got the `ftp_ssl_connect()` command which is a direct replacement to `ftp_connect()`. So I thought that anything else could stay the same in my code... But to my disappointment I couldn't get a remote file list using `ftp_nlist()` command (I'm getting a boolean false instead).

So let me give you the list of commands I used, and the outcome presented in the console:

```
$conn = ftp_ssl_connect( $ftp_address );
$login = ftp_login( $conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_password );
$files = ftp_nlist( $conn, '.' );

var_dump( $conn );
var_dump( $login );
var_dump( $files );
```

which returned

```
resource(4250) of type (FTP Buffer)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

I also tried using passive mode before `ftp_nlist()`, like this:

```
$conn = ftp_ssl_connect( $ftp_address );
$login = ftp_login( $conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_password );
ftp_pasv( $conn, true );
$files = ftp_nlist( $conn, '.' );

var_dump( $conn );
var_dump( $login );
var_dump( $files );
```

which returned a `PHP Warning:  ftp_nlist(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Permission denied (13) in`

Can someone give me an idea about why `ftp_nlist()` fails while the connection itself succeeds, and also give me a suggestion about how to deal with this? TIA!

Comment: Try `FTP_USEPASVADDRESS` along with ftp_pasv, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40720260/850848 + Can any commandline/GUI FTP client (running the machine where you PHP code fails) can list files on that FTP server?

Comment: According to the docs, `ftp_ssl_connect` is used for "FTP with explicit SSH" and not what you're looking for. FTP over SSH is somewhat complicated, you'll need to establish the SSH connection separately and operate 2 channels (data channel is SSH, the control channel is unsecured)- Nowadays you should be using SFTP. Here's a comparsion of different techniques https://www.awardspace.com/kb/what-is-ftp-over-ssh/#ftp-over-ssh-vs-sftp

Comment: @HonkderHase  You've got in a muddle between SSL (also known as TLS) and SSH. There's no mention of the incredibly rare "FTP over SSH" in the question; they were told to use "SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol", but also seemed able to connect with "FTP using explicit SSL", which is exactly what [ftp_ssl_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php) implements.

Comment: @IMSoPto be exact I mentioned that through a GUI FTP client I can connect and list files using both types, SFTP over SSH and FTP over Explicit SSL (Auth TLS). I only chose to use ftp_ssl_connect over ssh2 because ssh2 isn't installed on the server + I'm not familiar with it!

Comment: @MartinPrikrylyes, using the FTP Client I can list files successfully using FTP over SSL!

Comment: But do you run the FTP client on the *same machine* that runs your PHP code? + Did you try the `FTP_USEPASVADDRESS`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl no, the machine that runs the code is a linux webserver, the app ran from my local machine. In the code I tried the option FTP_USEPASVADDRESS before ftp_pasv(). Nothing changed!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I just used my code in a totally different server on a shared hosting I have on HG, and it does the exact same thing. `var_dump($ftpConn);
            var_dump($login);
            var_dump($files_array);` return `resource(4) of type (FTP Buffer)
bool(true)
bool(false)` respectively...

Comment: @MartinPrikryl would you care to help me a bit more with this? If yes, let me know so that I can PM you the connection info! This is the rest of the code I used:

`<?php
$host     = '***';
$username = '***';
$password = '***';

$conn  = ftp_ssl_connect( $host );
$login = ftp_login( $conn, $username, $password );

if ( $conn && $login ) {
    //ftp_set_option( $conn, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false );
    //ftp_pasv( $conn, true );

    $files = ftp_nlist( $conn, '.' );

    var_dump( $conn );
    var_dump( $login );
    var_dump( $files );
}`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl BTW, even with `FTP_USEPASVADDRESS` option in place, and `ftp_pasv`, I still get a warning mentioning: _Warning: ftp_nlist(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115)_

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I achieved what I needed with cURL, but TBH I'd like to see this working for the shake of knowledge, so if you wanna get involved in debugging this, do let me know!