# Feed output of a raw FTP command to a file

Tags: php

I'm trying to feed a `ftp_raw()` command's output to a file. More specifically, the command is `ftp_raw( $ftpConn, 'LIST -al' );` and I want to write the filelist to a file, or at least show it to the console screen...

I mean, I'm doing a `var_dump( ftp_raw( $ftpConn, 'LIST -al' ) );` and I'm correctly getting a response like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(42) "150 Opening data connection for file list."
}
```

but I also want to get the filelist itself somehow.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: The file list isn't sent as a response, it's sent over the data connection, just like when you download a file.

Comment: So it should be output to the console anyway? Are you sure about that? Cause I'm not getting anything

Comment: Why do you think that? The data connection is a new connection opened for each file transfer.

Comment: You need to study how the FTP protocol works. Or just use a higher-level interface instead of raw commands.

Comment: I tried `ftp_nlist()` but there is a problem I'm facing and tried to use a LIST instead...

Comment: You can take a look at my initial question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75968142/ftp-ssl-connect-and-ftp-nlist

Comment: [side-note]: if you use phpseclib PHP class, you may use something like `$sftp->nlist()`